BASIC Stamp Editor cannot find any usable ports even though Wine auto-links them
I am trying to use Basic Stamp Editor v2.5.4 by Parallax to program my Stamp 2 via the Board of education (the old kind with the RS232 port). I installed the editor via Wine 9.18 (staging), and it runs, but it cannot detect any serial ports. I checked via ls -l [wine prefix]/dosdevices and I can see that the serial device seems to be showing up properly: lrwxrwxrwx. 1 wilbur wilbur 12 Sep 28 20:44 com34 -> /dev/ttyUSB1 I know USB1 is the right device because when I plug and unplug it, I see corresponding dmesg debug about it. Note that I do have another serial device connected for a different purpose, which is why the Stamp isn’t connected to ttyUSB0. The program has the same symptoms in its own prefix and the default .wine one. In its own prefix, I tried adding a registry remap, (I.e., a string named COM1 with the value /dev/ttyUSB1, plus a string named COM34 with the value left blank, both under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\Ports), but to no effect. I tested the same adapter in Tiny Windows 11, and it worked, so I know this is either my Wine configuration, or possibly the program's compatibility with Wine. I doubt the latter because as you can see, it has an excellent track record even for very old Wine versions.
Edit: I notice that upon opening the editor software, the micro-controller resets if it is plugged in and on. I know this, because I used Windows to load a program on there that makes a sound.

You should show the details; eg the output of ls -l on the directory; eg your registry setting.  And "prefix_dir" isn't useful.

Added said details.
